# Utility to check time to execute?

Tags: python, shell, execution-time

Is there either a bash command or a Python library that will time the amount of time to execute a file/command? I want to be able to decide what language will work best for a task or have a way of knowing for certain that Python code A runs faster than Python code B. If there is a way of doing this, but this question is off topic, please leave a comment with search terms or other resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's called the `time` command. As in `time command arg1 arg2 arg3`.

This outputs 3 fields, something like this:

```
real    0m0.631s
user    0m0.154s
sys     0m0.458s
```

The first is the actual wall-clock time. The second is how long the program spent in user space. The third is how long the program spent in kernel space.

Answer (score 2):

You could use timeit:

```
from timeit import timeit
print timeit("function_2(arg)", "from __main__ import function_2, arg", number=5)
```

Things to note:

- `from __main__ import function, arg` gives the `timeit` module access to the functions and variables in the script.
- The function and associated arguments must be passed as strings.
- number = number of runs [defaults to 1000000].
- The time returned by timeit is the sum of `number` runs...NOT THE AVERAGE (caught me out once...).

Comment: While I did not accept this, I +1ed it. Too bad I can not accept multiples. :D Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`time`

For instance:

```
time ls -a
```

gives, after listing the files,

```
real    0m0.240s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.004s
```

There are many options for what to track in terms of resources. See the man page for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
python -m timeit "setup" "code"
```

if you want to time Python code. Useful for quick-and-dirty performance benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

I use this snippet, which I found online somewhere that I can't remember:

```
import atexit
import time
def secondsToStr(t):
    return "%d:%02d:%02d.%03d" % \
        reduce(lambda ll,b : divmod(ll[0],b) + ll[1:],
            [(t*1000,),1000,60,60])

line = "="*40
def log(s, elapsed=None):
    print line
    print secondsToStr(time.clock()), '-', s
    if elapsed:
        print "Elapsed time:", elapsed
    print line
    print

def endlog():
    end = time.clock()
    elapsed = end-start
    log("End Program", secondsToStr(elapsed))

def now():
    return secondsToStr(time.clock())

start = time.clock()
atexit.register(endlog)
log("Start Program")
```